# Turn page upside down using javascript when an image is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am making a troll website and one of the things the website needs to be able to do is turn the page upside down when an image is clicked. I want to do this using javascript. Would I use a function with an onclick?

Comment: Some people just  have no interest in research. They post and expect answer given to them.

Comment: But how could I implement it so that it happens when someone clicks something?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this CSS rule `transform: rotate(180deg);` to `body` tag when clicking the image